# Using &amp; in URL bugs up the $_GET

Tags: php, url

Running my site through http://validator.w3.org/check, I get a lot of error messages saying that my links should use `&amp;` in stead of `&`.

So I updated my code, only to find out that `$_GET` does not like this.

My URL was this: `www.mysite.com/?foo=1&bar=2`
and I changed it to this: `www.mysite.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2`

The problem is that doing a `print_r($_REQUEST)` gives me this result:

```
Array ( [foo] => 1 [amp;storeid] => 2 )
```

Why doesn't `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` recognize the `&amp;` ?

**UPDATE**
This is one of the ways I generate a URL:

```
$url = get_bloginfo('url')."/?foo=".$element['name']."&amp;bar=".$element['id'];
$link = '<a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$element['name'].'">'.$element['name'].'</a>';
```

Comment: How does the corresponding HTML source code look?

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML of that place?

Comment: What does "bugs up" mean?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`&amp;` is the HTML entity reference for `&`. URL parameters are still separated by a single `&`, but if you mention the URL in HTML, you need to encode it. For

```
<img src="img?width=100&amp;height=100" />
```

the browser then requests `img?width=100&height=100`.

Comment: `&amp;` is an entity reference. It references the entity named *amp* that’s value is `&#38;`.

Comment: Ah, That was it! Since I'm using WP, I just used `esc_url` and all my problems were solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You must be double-encoding somewhere, such that your link:

```
www.mysite.com/?foo=1&bar=2
```

becomes:

```
www.mysite.com/?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

and then:

```
www.mysite.com/?foo=1&amp;amp;bar=2
```

What you read is correct. To clarify, *in your HTML* `&` must be encoded as `&amp;`. Of course the URL itself still just contains `&`; PHP never sees "`&amp;`" because that encoding is for the benefit of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Fix for &amp; bug in url
if( $_GET ) foreach( $_GET as $key => $value )
{
    if( strpos( $key, 'amp;' ) === 0 )
    {
        $new_key = str_replace( 'amp;', '', $key );
        $_GET[ $new_key ] = $value;
        unset( $_GET[ $key ] );
    }
}
```

It won't work with filter_input :(

Answer (score 0):

In any case it's not a good practice to encode various URL parts by hands. You should do like this:

```
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($element['name']) . '&bar=' . urlencode($element['id']);
echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlspecialchars($query_string) . '">';
```

I think this will solve unneeded problems.