# How to encode '&' as '&amp;' in Liferay?

Tags: validation, liferay, liferay-6, w3c-validation

I tried to validate my Liferay site using http://validator.w3.org but I get many errors in the URLs:

> **Error:** `&` did not start a character reference. (`&` probably should have
>   been escaped as `&amp;`.)

How can I solve this errors in Liferay?

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: I am using `<!DOCTYPE html>` in HTML5

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322562/using-amp-in-url-bugs-up-the-get Another fix could be to change the usage of `&` to e.g. `;` in the server. Your URLs will then be `http://www.example.com/index.php?foo=bar;baz=goo`

Comment: Or you just accept the fact that W3 doesn't validate your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

In Liferay there is `HttpUtil`.
Package `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util`.

Generally to have the right encoding for http url and parameters use `HttpUtil.encodeURL`

Comment: Thank you so much. But how can I encode all the URLs of the Liferay Portal because there are 63 urls with that problem? I have to do something like this: `httpUtil.encodeURL(getPortalUrls,true)`?

Comment: Use a for each... no?

Comment: I can not modify the Liferay Portal sources, so I'm looking for a way to get all the URLs of the portal and then I will encode them.

Comment: this is not encoding '&' for me. any workaround for that?